# Calculation of Polish Expression

Tags: c++, polish-notation

i'm searching for something that explains how i can calculate an `Polish Expression`, example:

if i have this `((1+2)*4)+3`, in normal way is `1+2*4+3 = 15`, but i need to 
write this way: `12+4*3+` to using `stack` getting the value of top and putting in the stack again, see my code : https://ideone.com/0bdkkM

i already see one post but i dont understand how i can make the operations required: [StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6382/receber-uma-express%C3%A3o-e-calcular-em-c/6390#6390)

Comment: `1243+*+` is not a reverse Polish notation for `((1+2)*4)+3`. `12+4*3+` is.

Comment: Wikipedia has [an article with good explanation and algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) about RPN.

Comment: Nice SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023151/prefixpolish-notation-evaluation-c

Comment: @Igor Actually, `1 2 + 4 * 3 +` :)

Comment: edited this right now

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, are you trying to convert an expression to reverse polish (1+2 to 1 2 +), or are you trying to evaluate a reverse polish expression (1 2 + to 3) ?

Comment: @Sean in this code i got the expression `12+4*3+` now i need to obtain the result  15, the polish expression i already have i need to now how i use the stack to get the result; https://ideone.com/ilJFok

Comment: Your code should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple RPN evaluator, without any error handling. You only need a stack to store the operands, not the operators, which makes it pretty easy to implement.

Note that this version assumes the operands are single digit numbers on the input expression. I've done this to simplify parsing the RPN expression. In real life you'd want to handle multi-digit operands.

```
std::stack<int> stack;

const char *expression="12+4*3+";

for(char c=*expression; c!=0; c=*expression++)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '+':
        {
            int rhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int lhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int result=lhs+rhs;
            stack.push(result);
            break;
        }

        case '-':
        {
            int rhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int lhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int result=lhs-rhs;
            stack.push(result);
            break;
        }

        case '*':
        {
            int rhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int lhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int result=lhs*rhs;
            stack.push(result);
            break;
        }

        case '/':
        {
            int rhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int lhs=stack.top();    stack.pop();
            int result=lhs/rhs;
            stack.push(result);
            break;
        }

        default:
            int number=(c-'0');
            stack.push(number);
            break;
    }
}

int final_result=stack.top();
std::cout << "result is " << final_result << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason Reverse Polish became popular is because it maps nicely to the computer concept of a stack.

When the user enters a number, push it on the stack.

When the user enters an operator, pop 2 numbers from the stack, calculate the result, and push the result back on the stack.

Comment: You also need to consider operator precedence

Comment: @Sean no you don't, that's what makes Reverse Polish so simple. The user is responsible for rearranging the expression for precedence.

Comment: It does if you're converting the expression to RPN.

Comment: @Sean the question was about *calculating* a Reverse Polish expression, not *converting* one.

Comment: you have some example in code ? in my code i do one dynamics stack  to receive the numbers, them i create one vector to get the operators, but i need to create another dynamic stack or using the same dynamics stack understand ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues do the calculations as you accept the operators, no need to store them.